# Mountain Lion: Launching App by dragging files on its Icon causes weird start-up-delay and other problems in the process

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

A quick way to reproduce this (ML, Xcode 441):
- New Cocoa Application (all project options "off")
- add a Document Type with "Role > Viewer" and "Extensions > *"
- add the following code to the appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)path
{
    NSLog(@"%@", path);
    return YES;
}
```

> "Run" ... -> Quick launchtime, and the window is visible immediately.
> Now launch the App by dragging a file on its icon ... -> Quick launch (-applicationDidFinishLaunching:), but it takes almost five seconds for the window to appear!

What happens in these 5 seconds?

A simple workaround SEEMS to be something like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [_window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

Now the window is immediately visible even when launching the App by dragging files on its icon.
BUT there are other problems that this workaround does not fix:

- Now in MainMenu.xib set the Window to "Full Screen > Primary Window"

> "Build"

> launch the App by dragging  a file on its icon, wait 5 seconds, enter "Full Screen"-mode -> no problems, no redraw issues (EXIT "Full Screen", quit)

> launch the App by dragging  a file on its icon, IMMEDIATELY enter "Full Screen"-mode -> display problems: there is no linen background, but instead the window in fullscreen-state is visible as the background behind the zooming animation!? (stay in "Full Screen", quit)

> launch the app by doubleclick -> without problems the app is back in "Full Screen"-mode (stay in "Full Screen", quit)

> launch the App by dragging  a file on its icon -> The App-Window enters fullscreen-state (-windowDidEnterFullScreen:), but there is no "space-change" so the fullscreen-window is not visible. And its NOT possible to switch to this space immediately (e.g. by clicking the App-Icon). You have to wait the 5 seconds to be able to do this!

So it looks like even these Fullscreen-problems have to do with the 5 second-delay we saw at the beginning!?


Is this a Mountain Lion Bug (Seems not to happen in Lion this way) or is this expected behaviour? Am I missing something really obvious? Is there a workaround?
I need my App to reliably enter FullScreen-mode even on App-launch! Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!